# perform a statistical test on specific data in ggplot2 

Tags: r, ggplot2

i wrote a script that generate plots using ggplot2 , and in each plot there is multiple x-axis value and each one of them have multiple values on the y-axis for multiple variables on this axis.

i will ask the question in another way : i have multiple subset of data in a data frame , generated inside a for loop , how can i control the looping of the for in order to generate another data frame that contain in each row (the value of the first column of the previous data frames)

```
for (x in phy) {
    print(x)

    test<-subset(t, Phylum==x)
    dat <- melt(test, measure=c("A","C","G","T","(A-T)/(A+T)","(G-C)/(G+T)",
                                "(A+T)/(G+C)"))
    unitest <- unique(c(test$Class))
    #print(nrow(test))
    i <- 1
    for(y in unitest) {
        towork <- subset(test, Class==y)

        # here i want to create a data frame that will contain (in each row, the
        # value of the first column of the towork subset for each y)

        # atest=wilcox.test(towork$A,towork$A, correct=FALSE)
        # print(paste(paste(y,towork$A),towork$A))
    }
}



input:

    e.g 
    class1:
    0.268912    0.158921    0.214082    0.358085
    1.680946         0.314681   0.210526    0.166895
    0.286945    0.322006    0.147361    0.243688
    class2
    0.293873    0.327516    0.156235    0.222376    
    0.327430    0.308667    0.135710    0.227695    
    0.301488    0.326511    0.125865    0.246022    
    0.310980    0.308730    0.148861    0.231429
```

i want to the new data frame to contain in each row the first column of each class.

```
output
    e.g
    1st row: 0.268912 1.680946 0.286945
    2nd row:0.293873 0.327430 0.301488 0.310980
```

etc...
and then another data frame that contain in each row the 2nd column of each class
etc...

than i want to perform a statistical test on each 2 row of the new data frame together (e.g Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test) and get the result.

any help would be appreciated

```
Hello , i came up with an idea , but i need your help to do it.
first the data is in a large text file and i will upload it if you want , my idea is : create a function that take 2 argument : 
1.the name of the column which should be used for grouping the data (e.g. phylum, or class)
2. the name of the column containing the data to test (e.g. A,C,G,T)
and i will test the data for each phylum first , and if i want i will test it for each class in each phylum.
that's mean,i will take the A column for first phylum and A column for 2nd phylum and make the wilcox.test on them ,  and i will make the process for each common column in each phylum. and then i will use a subset function to test the classes inside each phylum.  
give me your opininon with this ??
```

thnx in advance.

Comment: @abd - sample input data and expected output please. use `dput` for any objects that are needed to run your code.

Comment: @ Chase: thank you for your reply.
each y contain the following varaibles :A C G T 
e.g 0.268912 0.158921 0.214082 0.358085 -0.142223 0.096408 1.680946         0.314681 0.210526 0.166895 0.307898 0.010895

Comment: @Chase: thank you for your reply , i just edited the question , and forget about my previous comment , thanks in advance

Comment: @Chase: Hello Chase, is there a solution for my problem ?? 
thanks.

Comment: The answer is almost certainly yes but it still isn't clear what you want. The `melt` in the for loop at the top references 7 measure variables implying there are at least 7 variables in your data.frame(s), but your example data.frames at the bottom only contain four columns. Is what you want to do is take the first column of class1 and compute the wilcox.test with the first column of class2? What about the other columns in the data.frames? Do you also want to compute the wilcox.test for them?

Comment: @Chase: thanks for your reply, i want only 4 new data frames for these 4 variables (A,C,G,T). for example in the Adataframe i want to take each A column from each class and place it as a row in the Adataframe in order to run the wilcox.test on each pair of row together(or each A vector for each 2 class together), and you idea is right(take the first column of class1 and compute the wilcox.test with the first column of class2) i want this for the 4 first variables only, is it clear now ??

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you are after. We don't necessarily need to go through the process of making new data.frames for the four variables of interest - we can extract the columns of interest from their respective locations within `class1` and `class2`. Code has been updated to find the common columns between class1 and class2. It will only compute the wilcox test for those common columns.

```
class1 <- matrix(rnorm(12), ncol = 4)
class2 <- matrix(rnorm(16), ncol = 4)

computeWilcox <- function(x, y, correct = FALSE, ...) {

    if (!is.numeric(x)) stop("x must be numeric.")
    if (!is.numeric(y)) stop("y must be numeric.")

    commonCols <- intersect(colnames(x), colnames(y))

    ret <- vector("list", length(commonCols))

    for (col in 1:length(commonCols)) {
        ret[[col]] <- wilcox.test(x[, col], y[, col], correct = correct, ...)
    }

    names(ret) <- commonCols
    return(ret)
}


zz <- computeWilcox(class1, class2)
```

Where zz has a structure like:

```
> str(zz)
List of 2
 $ c:List of 7
  ..$ statistic  : Named num 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "W"
  ..$ parameter  : NULL
  ..$ p.value    : num 0.0571
  ..$ null.value : Named num 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "location shift"
  ..$ alternative: chr "two.sided"
  ..$ method     : chr "Wilcoxon rank sum test"
  ..$ data.name  : chr "x[, col] and y[, col]"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
 $ d:List of 7
  ..$ statistic  : Named num 2
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "W"
  ..$ parameter  : NULL
  ..$ p.value    : num 0.229
  ..$ null.value : Named num 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "location shift"
  ..$ alternative: chr "two.sided"
  ..$ method     : chr "Wilcoxon rank sum test"
  ..$ data.name  : chr "x[, col] and y[, col]"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

You can extract the parameter or p-value out of the returned list object like this:

```
> zz$c$p.value
[1] 0.05714286
```

Comment: @Chase: Hello , the classes that i want to extract the data from are dynamically changing for each phylum(in the  first for) soo each phylum has a different number of classes, what i want to do is that the wilcox.test will be applied on 2 class of each phylum together(1st and 2nd , 3rd and 4th , ...), and to display result inside the plot pdf. is this can be done ?? thanks

Comment: @Chase: Hello , that's what i want , but there still 1 thing missing , how should i automate the process of testing the classes for each phylum??  because each phylum has more than 1 class , and each class have 4 column(A,C,G,T) , and i want to test each (e.g A column) of each 2 class from each phylum together , and each (e.g G column) of each 2 class of each phylum together, how this can be done ?? and sorry for bothering :S

Comment: @abd - that will depend on where the data is coming from and how you have it structured in your working environment. Is everything in one big data.frame? Lots of little data.frames? A list object with data.frames? The solution will likely entail a call to `apply` or some grouping function, but it's impossible to say without a representative example of your data. If you go back to my first comment and `dput` the contents of whatever the object is that you are trying to work with - that will be the easiest way to move forward. `dput` will allows others to simply copy and paste the object in R

Comment: @Chase: i edited my question , because what i wrote was very large , you will find it in a code tag . waiting your opinion to start the work and get your help :) , thanks

Comment: @Chase: mediafire.com/?3m3mataw9nlzm1m 

that's the file containing the whole data

Comment: @abd - that looks like an image file?

Comment: @Chase: i wrote a function that will make what i want , but i had a problem passing string parametre to it , how can i do this easily ??